# Join with 'on' that contains a parameter string - EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a complex sql statement that I'm trying to convert to EF and I have only one problem left with it.

This is the part in question in SQL

```
inner join history_master h2
on h.taskid=h2.taskid and h2.file_no = 'REX223349'
```

and I'm trying that in EF but I can't figure out how to pas the file_no as a parameter.

I tried:

```
.Join(context.History_master, h => new { h.h.h.taskid, h.h.h.file_no }, h2 => new { h2.taskid, h2.file_no.Where(fileNumber) }, (h, h2) => new { h, h2 }) 
//fileNumber is a string passed to the function
```

I thought this would perform the join on the `taskid` and `h2.file_no = 'REX223349'` but instead it gives me an error.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here? How can I pass a string to EF so the join will be performed as in above SQL statement? Let me know if you need more details or you need something explained. It was rather difficult to put this problem into words that made sense :/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var result = (from t in context.Task
    join h in context.History_mast on new (taskID = t.taskID, File_no = "REX223349") equals new (taskID = h.taskID, File_no = h.File_no)
    select new (t,h));
```